# argsparse for parsing nested optional arguments in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse, args

I am trying to write a parsing for my python script where the command parameters should be in the following order,

**OUTPUT :** 
`cli unmount [-h] -f FS_NAME [-n NODE_SPEC] [--evict [--force]]]`

I am able to write the code for rest of the commands except for the last one. `[--evict [--force]]`. This means that `--force` argument will only apply if `--evict` is given.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('CLI demo')
sub_parser = parser.add_subparsers()
unmount = sub_parser.add_parser('unmount')
unmount.add_argument("-f", "--fs", dest="fs_name", required=True, help="filesystem name.")
unmount.add_argument("-n", "--nodes", dest="nodes", metavar='NODE_SPEC', help="pdsh style nodes hostnames (If this parameters ")
```

These are the two approaches I have taken for adding the optional child argument, `--force` to the optional parent argument, `--evict`,

**Approach 1:**

```
evict_parser = unmount.add_subparsers()
evict = evict_parser.add_parser("--evict", help="evict lustre clients before unmount.")
evict.add_argument("--force", dest="force", action="store_true", default=False, help="force mode for evict lustre clients.")
parser.parse_args()
```

and **Approach 2:**

```
parent_cmd_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=F)
parent_cmd_parser.add_argument("--force", dest="force", action="store_true", default=False, help="force mode for evict lustre clients.")
evict_parser = unmount.add_subparsers()
evict = evict_parser.add_parser("--evict",  help="evict lustre clients before unmount.", parents=[parent_cmd_parser])
```

Unfortunately none is working. In first case I am not getting the desired help output/usage help and in the second the `--force` argument is hidden.

Comment: What should happen if `--force` is used without `--evict`?  What if it is given first?

Comment: @hpaulj, in that case it would be error. since --force would be enabled only  if --evict is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argparse` doesn't support interdependent arguments directly.

Just add `--force` as a *regular* argument, document that it only applies when `--evict` is given, and give an error when `--force` is used without `--evict`:

```
if args.force and not args.evict:
    parser.error('--force can only be used together with --evict')
```

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by 'support independent arguments directly'? Does that mean it adding a child argument to another argument?

Comment: @BhupeshPant: yes, 'interdependent' means arguments that depend on other arguments.

Comment: oh I see, Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to define `--evict` with `nargs='?'`, and define both `default` and `const`.

```
parser.add_argument('--evict', nargs='?', default='noEvict', const='EvictWOArgument')
```

Then `args.evict` will be either 'noEvict', 'EvictWOArgument', or what ever string the user gave (e.g. 'force').  You can choose any values and interpretation that is convenient.  You could even use 'choices':

```
In [2]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()    
In [4]: parser.add_argument('-e','--evict',nargs='?',choices=['force'],default=False, const=True)

In [5]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[5]: Namespace(evict=False)

In [6]: parser.parse_args(['-e'])
Out[6]: Namespace(evict=True)

In [7]: parser.parse_args(['-e','test'])
usage: ipython3.5 [-h] [-e [{force}]]
ipython3.5: error: argument -e/--evict: invalid choice: 'test' (choose from 'force')
...

In [8]: parser.parse_args(['-e','force'])
Out[8]: Namespace(evict='force')
```

If the patch in http://bugs.python.org/issue9334 is ever implemented, it might be possible to define '--force' as a `choice`.  Currently the parser classifies, early on in parsing, such as string an optionals flag.  Such usage could also confuse the end user - is `--force` an optional that can go anywhere, or a argument that must follow `--evict`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @hpaulj. This can certainly help me with my purpose. But I am still stuck in one thing. I am getting error when I am trying to  do parser.parse_args(['unmount','-f file_node','--evict', '--force']) with this line of code, unmount_parser.add_argument('--evict',nargs='?',choices=['--force'],default=False, const=True). But when I am using force instead of --force its working though. I wanted force to be --force. This is because I don't want to break existing functionality.

Comment: Right, the parser treats a `'--force'` string as a optionals flag, not as an argument.  There is a backlogged patch (9334) that would add a `args_default_to_positional` parameter which would change this behavior.